# Kernel isn't upgraded since 3.19.0-25

Tags: grub2, apt, kernel, 15.04, 15.10

I noticed yesterday, that my kernel wasn't up-to-date, even though I installed updates.

I checked the installed packages and all newer linux-header* packages were installed up to the current 4.2 kernel in Ubuntu 15.10.

I checked my /boot folder and there were no newer kernel images. After seeing that, I removed all but the current kernel which, interestingly, didn't clean up my /boot folder [old kernel images were still there, I deleted them by hand now], then installed the newest kernel, but again with no success.

I also tried to just run `apt-get install --reinstall` on the kernel packages, but no dice either.

I checked all logs (dmesg, dpkg, syslog) I could think of but couldn't find any errors or warnings.

So with no further information about what is happening, I hope that someone here can help me figure out what's going on with my system.

History of this system:

Original 14.04, was upgraded to 14.10, then to 15.04, then to 15.10. Kernel updates, apparently, stopped working while Ubuntu 15.04 was installed.

Partitions:

- /boot is a seperate partition. GRUB is installed here (already re-installed it with no change). (SSD)
- /home is a seperate partition. (SSD)
- / is a sperate partition (SSD)
- /var and /tmp are seperate partitions on my second harddrive

SSD is /dev/sdb, harddrive is /dev/sda.

Comment: @kos That is a bad idea to suggest mainline kernels here.

Comment: @Pilot6 You're right, I removed the close vote. I didn't notice the question was about installing from mainline.

Comment: I'll click the button/edit my question when I get home. Thank's for bringing that question to my attention. @Pilot6

Comment: Yeah it's a duplicate. My problem was solved by installing the mentioned package.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

It will install the correct version of kernel headers.

Comment: I did that as well. From my understanding it's just a meta-package that always links to the current kernel anyway. Anyway, it doesn't make a difference.

Interesting thing though: If I try to install (after uninstalling) that package via synaptic, I can't. Usually you select a package and say install and the checkbox next to it is marked. But with that package, the checkbox is colored red and if I click 'Install packages' it just says that the package is defect. Installing with apt-get works, though.